# External ip always <none> or <pending> in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, raspberry-pi3, nginx-ingress

Recently i started building my very own kubernetes cluster using a few Raspberry pi's.

I have gotten to the point where i have a cluster up and running!

Some background info on how i setup the cluster, i used [this guide](https://medium.com/nycdev/k8s-on-pi-9cc14843d43)

But now, when i want to deploy and expose an application i encounter some issues...

Following the kubernetes tutorials i have made an deployment of nginx, this is running fine. when i do a port-forward i can see the default nginx page on my localhost.

Now the tricky part, creating an service and routing the traffic from the internet through an ingress to the service.

i have executed the following command's

```
kubectl expose deployment/nginx --type="NodePort" --port 80
kubectl expose deployment/nginx --type="Loadbalancer" --port 80
```

And these result in the following.

```
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1     <none>        443/TCP          25h
nginx        NodePort    10.103.77.5   <none>        80:30106/TCP   7m50s
```

```
NAME         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP      10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP        25h
nginx        LoadBalancer   10.107.233.191   <pending>     80:31332/TCP   4s
```

The external ip address never shows, which makes it quite impossible for me to access the application from outside of the cluster by doing `curl some-ip:80` which in the end is the whole reason for me to setup this cluster.

If any of you have some clear guides or advice i can work with it would be really appreciated!

Note: 
I have read things about LoadBalancer, this is supposed to be provided by the cloud host. since i run on RPI i don't think this will work for me. but i believe NodePort should be just fine to route with an ingress.

Also i am aware of the fact that i should have an ingress-controller of some sort for ingress to work.

## Edit

So i have the following now for the nodeport - 30168

```
$ kubectl get svc
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP        26h
nginx        NodePort    10.96.125.112   <none>        80:30168/TCP   6m20s
```

and for the ip address i have either `192.168.178.102` or `10.44.0.1`

```
$ kubectl describe pod nginx-688b66fb9c-jtc98
Node:               k8s-worker-2/192.168.178.102
IP:                 10.44.0.1
```

But when i enter either of these ip addresses in the browser with the nodeport i still don't see the nginx page. am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are not in a cloud provider, you need to use [MetalLB](https://metallb.universe.tf/) to have the LoadBalancer features working.

> Kubernetes does not offer an implementation of network load-balancers (Services of type LoadBalancer) for bare metal clusters. The implementations of Network LB that Kubernetes does ship with are all glue code that calls out to various IaaS platforms (GCP, AWS, Azure…). If you’re not running on a supported IaaS platform (GCP, AWS, Azure…), LoadBalancers will remain in the “pending” state indefinitely when created.
>
> Bare metal cluster operators are left with two lesser tools to bring user traffic into their clusters, “NodePort” and “externalIPs” services. Both of these options have significant downsides for production use, which makes bare metal clusters second class citizens in the Kubernetes ecosystem.
>
> MetalLB aims to redress this imbalance by offering a Network LB implementation that integrates with standard network equipment, so that external services on bare metal clusters also “just work” as much as possible

The MetalLB [setup](https://metallb.universe.tf/installation/) is very easy:

`kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/metallb/v0.8.3/manifests/metallb.yaml`

> This will deploy MetalLB to your cluster, under the metallb-system namespace

You need to create a configMap with the ip range you want to use, create a file named `metallb-cf.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  namespace: metallb-system
  name: config
data:
  config: |
    address-pools:
    - name: default
      protocol: layer2
      addresses:
      - 192.168.1.240-192.168.1.250 <= Select the range you want.
```

`kubectl apply -f metallb-cf.yaml`

That's all.

To use on your services just create with type `LoadBalancer` and MetalLB will do the rest. If you want to customize the configuration see [here](https://metallb.universe.tf/usage/)

MetalLB will assign a IP for your service/ingress, but if you are in a NAT network you need to configure your router to forward the requests for your ingress/service IP.

**EDIT:**

You have problem to get External IP with MetalLB running on Raspberry Pi, try to change iptables to legacy version:

```
sudo sysctl net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables=1
sudo update-alternatives --set iptables /usr/sbin/iptables-legacy
```

**Reference:** https://www.shogan.co.uk/kubernetes/building-a-raspberry-pi-kubernetes-cluster-part-2-master-node/

I hope that helps.

Comment: If i understand this correctly i can use the MetalLB instead of an ingress and nginx-ingress controller? or is it usefull to have both? (gonna try this out tomorrow, gonna accept your answer if it worked out for me!)

Comment: Metallb just provide an "abstraction layer" to assign a ip of your network to a service/ingress. You could have both, they not are interfere one each other.

Comment: @Ricardo `ingress` is just a configuration slice for `ingress-controller` which in turn can deployed over a `NodePort` or `LoadBalancer` type service. deploying it over the `LoadBalancer` will give you all its advantages, which is mainly a single stable VIP. Now Ingress operates on HTTP level gives you all L7 advantages, like virtual hosts, URL rewriting, real client IP in the headers etc which a load balancer can't give you on its own. So it definitely makes sense to have a MetalLB and ingress :)

Comment: Currently I am in a struggle with getting the ingress controller up and running on the pi. As this does not yet work. But I have the metal lb installed and made a LoadBalancer type ingress service. Which should have an external op according to the docs. But that is not the case yet. So I’ll post an update the moment I get out of the ingress controller issue

Comment: @Ricardo, Recently I had a problem to setup MetalLB in Raspberry PI 3B+. I was using Kubernetes 1.16.5 with MetalLB and my service didn't get External IP address. I see in [this](https://www.shogan.co.uk/kubernetes/building-a-raspberry-pi-kubernetes-cluster-part-2-master-node/) blog a problem regard iptables and after applied the suggested command the problem was solved. I've update my answer with this command

Comment: @rabello I go and have a look at this either tonight or tomorrow. Did not have time to play with my cluster yet. But thank you so much for the continues help! really appreciated. Expect the accepted flag tonight or tommorow :)

Answer (score 3):

Any of your worker nodes' IP address will work for a `NodePort` (or `LoadBalancer`) service.  From [the description of `NodePort` services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport) :

> If you set the `type` field to `NodePort`, the Kubernetes control plane allocates a port from a range specified by `--service-node-port-range` flag (default: 30000-32767). Each node proxies that port (the same port number on every Node) into your Service.

If you don't know those IP addresses `kubectl get nodes` can tell you; if you're planning on calling them routinely then setting up a load balancer in front of the cluster or configuring DNS (or both!) can be helpful.

In your example, say some node has the IP address 10.20.30.40 (you log into the Raspberry PI directly and run `ifconfig` and that's the host's address); you can reach the nginx from the second example at `http://10.20.30.40:31332`.

The `EXTERNAL-IP` field will never fill in for a `NodePort` service, or when you're not in a cloud environment that can provide an external load balancer for you.  That doesn't affect this case, for either of these service types you can still call the port on the node directly.