# Kubernetes on bare metal, exposing services through ingress

Tags: kubernetes

## The problem

I have a kubernetes cluster installed with a loadbalancer which gives me an external IP, but when i try to reach the IP address i get an timeout...

this only happens when i try to acces a service through the ingress, when exposing the service directly with a loadbalancer i get direct response.

### Current setup

I have had another question about making the cluster [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60149426/external-ip-always-none-or-pending-in-kubernetes), maybe there is some info in there that can be used to add on this question.

**My ingress file**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: dev-ingress
  annotations:
     kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: httpd
          servicePort: 80
```

**My service file**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2020-02-18T19:37:44Z"
  labels:
    app: httpd
  name: httpd
  namespace: development
  resourceVersion: "513069"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/development/services/httpd
  uid: a0b54ecf-6481-4047-b242-6a6c76df4e70
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.99.124.218
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: httpd
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

### Situation explained

When i do `kubectl port-forward <pod-name> 80` and then `curl localhost:80` I get a response from the httpd service with the default "It works!" page.

**Retrieving the external ip from the loadbalancer**

```
$ kubectl get ing
NAME          HOSTS   ADDRESS            PORTS   AGE
dev-ingress   *       <my external IP>   80      18h
```

**Pinging the exposed IP address by the loadbalancer**

```
$ ping <my external IP>

Pinging <my external IP> with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
```

## Edit

logs of the ingress-controller pod. (there are no new logs as soon as i ping or curl the external ip)

```
$ kubectl logs -f nginx-ingress-controller-5d7fc968df-992zf -n ingress-nginx
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NGINX Ingress controller
  Release:       0.29.0
  Build:         git-eedcdcdbf
  Repository:    https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx
  nginx version: nginx/1.17.8

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

W0219 14:49:56.568453       7 flags.go:260] SSL certificate chain completion is disabled (--enable-ssl-chain-completion=false)
W0219 14:49:56.568838       7 client_config.go:543] Neither --kubeconfig nor --master was specified.  Using the inClusterConfig.  This might not work.
I0219 14:49:56.569749       7 main.go:193] Creating API client for https://10.96.0.1:443
I0219 14:49:56.716103       7 main.go:237] Running in Kubernetes cluster version v1.17 (v1.17.2) - git (clean) commit 59603c6e503c87169aea6106f57b9f242f64df89 - platform linux/arm
I0219 14:50:01.502630       7 main.go:102] SSL fake certificate created /etc/ingress-controller/ssl/default-fake-certificate.pem
I0219 14:50:01.676803       7 nginx.go:263] Starting NGINX Ingress controller
I0219 14:50:01.856152       7 event.go:281] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"ConfigMap", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"udp-services", UID:"c8ed6c41-dfd2-41b3-a6bd-4a5cac469346", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"442237", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'CREATE' ConfigMap ingress-nginx/udp-services
I0219 14:50:01.856531       7 event.go:281] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"ConfigMap", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"nginx-configuration", UID:"0006891d-43cd-46d1-a1b8-4e4b123cd1f6", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"442235", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'CREATE' ConfigMap ingress-nginx/nginx-configuration
I0219 14:50:01.882095       7 event.go:281] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"ConfigMap", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"tcp-services", UID:"65a44b89-c6c2-4126-bee3-6c72e039df49", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"442236", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'CREATE' ConfigMap ingress-nginx/tcp-services
I0219 14:50:02.991815       7 event.go:281] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"development", Name:"dev-ingress", UID:"ad997038-c7e3-4e33-bec1-7305daff8cc0", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1beta1", ResourceVersion:"525710", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'CREATE' Ingress development/dev-ingress
I0219 14:50:03.077935       7 nginx.go:307] Starting NGINX process
I0219 14:50:03.078415       7 leaderelection.go:242] attempting to acquire leader lease  ingress-nginx/ingress-controller-leader-nginx...
I0219 14:50:03.082313       7 controller.go:137] Configuration changes detected, backend reload required.
I0219 14:50:03.101026       7 status.go:86] new leader elected: nginx-ingress-controller-5d7fc968df-jgz2t
I0219 14:50:03.449249       7 controller.go:153] Backend successfully reloaded.
I0219 14:50:03.450116       7 controller.go:162] Initial sync, sleeping for 1 second.
I0219 14:50:55.465109       7 leaderelection.go:252] successfully acquired lease ingress-nginx/ingress-controller-leader-nginx
I0219 14:50:55.465113       7 status.go:86] new leader elected: nginx-ingress-controller-5d7fc968df-992zf
```

**metalLB controller logs**

```
{"caller":"main.go:108","configmap":"metallb-system/config","event":"startUpdate","msg":"start of config update","ts":"2020-02-19T15:02:13.512307096Z"}
{"caller":"main.go:121","configmap":"metallb-system/config","event":"endUpdate","msg":"end of config update","ts":"2020-02-19T15:02:13.512598915Z"}
{"caller":"k8s.go:376","configmap":"metallb-system/config","event":"configLoaded","msg":"config (re)loaded","ts":"2020-02-19T15:02:13.512757194Z"}
{"caller":"main.go:49","event":"startUpdate","msg":"start of service update","service":"kube-system/kube-dns","ts":"2020-02-19T15:02:13.51819962Z"}
{"caller":"service.go:33","event":"clearAssignment","msg":"not a LoadBalancer","reason":"notLoadBalancer","service":"kube-system/kube-dns","ts":"2020-02-19T15:02:13.518476596Z"}
{"caller":"main.go:75","event":"noChange","msg":"service converged, no change","service":"kube-system/kube-dns","ts":"2020-02-19T15:02:13.518964089Z"}
{"caller":"main.go:76","event":"endUpdate","msg":"end of service update","service":"kube-system/kube-dns","ts":"2020-02-19T15:02:13.519145076Z"}
{"caller":"main.go:49","event":"startUpdate","msg":"start of service update","service":"default/kubernetes","ts":"2020-02-19T15:02:13.519351115Z"}
{"caller":"service.go:33","event":"clearAssignment","msg":"not a LoadBalancer","reason":"notLoadBalancer","service":"default/kubernetes","ts":"2020-02-19T15:02:13.51972585Z"}
{"caller":"main.go:75","event":"noChange","msg":"service converged, no change","service":"default/kubernetes","ts":"2020-02-19T15:02:13.520109699Z"}
{"caller":"main.go:76","event":"endUpdate","msg":"end of service update","service":"default/kubernetes","ts":"2020-02-19T15:02:13.520263603Z"}
{"caller":"main.go:49","event":"startUpdate","msg":"start of service update","service":"development/httpd","ts":"2020-02-19T15:02:13.520447767Z"}
{"caller":"service.go:33","event":"clearAssignment","msg":"not a LoadBalancer","reason":"notLoadBalancer","service":"development/httpd","ts":"2020-02-19T15:02:13.520622087Z"}
{"caller":"main.go:75","event":"noChange","msg":"service converged, no change","service":"development/httpd","ts":"2020-02-19T15:02:13.520975572Z"}
{"caller":"main.go:76","event":"endUpdate","msg":"end of service update","service":"development/httpd","ts":"2020-02-19T15:02:13.521132393Z"}
{"caller":"main.go:49","event":"startUpdate","msg":"start of service update","service":"ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx","ts":"2020-02-19T15:02:13.521314318Z"}
{"caller":"main.go:75","event":"noChange","msg":"service converged, no change","service":"ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx","ts":"2020-02-19T15:02:13.521901705Z"}
{"caller":"main.go:76","event":"endUpdate","msg":"end of service update","service":"ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx","ts":"2020-02-19T15:02:13.522087797Z"}
```

Comment: logs from Nginx ingress controller pod? Are. you using metalLB?

Comment: Yes i am using metalLB, do you wish to see any logs or config of that aswell?

Comment: metallb pod logs will help

Comment: do you have firewall blocking it ?

Comment: The router i have recieved from my ISP comes with a firewall which is enabled. Sadly enough i cannot see the rules that are configured by them...

Comment: But there is an setting called "ip-filter" for the sake of testing i have set the following:  source-ip=* target-ip=* protocol=* port=* target-port=*. pinging the external ip provided by the loadbalancer, still nothing happened. Also, disabling the firewall did not change a thing

Comment: I also have a plex server, this one somehow configured itself using upnp. But it has a port-forward in the router. This could be an idea for my k8s cluster. but the ip i get from the loadbalancer is not any of the ip's of the raspberry pi's